# Font issue in Asymptote 3D Texlive 2022

Tags: fonts, texlive, asymptote

The following code works with texlive 2021 but no longer with texlive 2022.

```
    % !TeX program = lualatex
    \documentclass{article}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
    \begin{document}

    Alors?

    \begin{asydef}
        texpreamble("\usepackage[math-style=french,bold-style=ISO]{fourier-otf}");
        texpreamble("\setmainfont[Scale=0.72]{Verdana}");
        settings.tex="lualatex";
        \end{asydef}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{asy}
    import three;
    unitsize(1cm);
    //draw('en 2D : $A$ et A',(0,0)--(10,0));
    draw('en 3D : $B$ et B',(0,0,0)--(10,0,0));
            \end{asy}
        \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

No problem in 2D, but in 3D, no longer generates the pdf properly, the draw inthe pdf and the text only on _ps with
asy -f pdf essai-1.asy

MODIFIED after the comment.
Système d’exploitation 64 bits, processeur x64
Windows 10 Famille

[image]

The code asy generated

```
    if(!settings.multipleView) settings.batchView=false;
    settings.tex="pdflatex";
    settings.inlinetex=true;
    deletepreamble();
    defaultfilename="essai-1";
    if(settings.render < 0) settings.render=4;
    settings.outformat="";
    settings.inlineimage=true;
    settings.embed=true;
    settings.toolbar=false;
    viewportmargin=(2,2);

    texpreamble("\usepackage[math-style=french,bold-style=ISO]{fourier-otf}");
    texpreamble("\setmainfont[Scale=0.72]{Verdana}");
    settings.tex="lualatex";

    import three;
    unitsize(1cm);
    //draw('en 2D : $A$ et A',(0,0)--(10,0));
    draw('en 3D : $B$ et B',(0,0,0)--(10,0,0));
```

The files genrated

[image]

The file essai-1__.ps
[image]

The file essai-1_0.pdf
[image]

Comment: You should post this issue to https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/issues to get a quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded TeXLive 2022.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/asy -f pdf
```

works fine, where test.asy contains the lines

```
import three;
unitsize(1cm);
draw('en 3D : $B$ et B',(0,0,0)--(10,0,0));
```

Please check that your version of asy was compiled with 3D support,
using `asy --version`. The x86_64-linux version returns

```
Asymptote version 2.79 [(C) 2004 Andy Hammerlindl, John C. Bowman, Tom Prince]

ENABLED OPTIONS:
V3D      3D vector graphics output
WebGL    3D HTML rendering
OpenGL   3D OpenGL rendering
SSBO     GLSL shader storage buffer objects
XDR      External Data Representation (portable binary file format for V3D)
Readline Interactive history and editing
GC       Boehm garbage collector
threads  Render OpenGL in separate thread

DISABLED OPTIONS:
GSL      GNU Scientific Library (special functions)
FFTW3    Fast Fourier transforms
CURL     URL support
LSP      Language Server Protocol
Sigsegv  Distinguish stack overflows from segmentation faults
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I modified the EDIT to show the version of asymptote used. I work on windows 10. I think it's on the side of lualatex, because it's the same version of asymptote. I don't see what I forgot to do after installation.

Comment: It works fine without change of font

Comment: @John Bowman: your simple test.asy works, but if you add a first line like "settings.tex=xelatex" (or "settings.tex=lualatex") it doesn't work any more :(

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I should not open a new question. Should I?

Let's look at the test.asy file by John Bowman. If I add a first line:

```
settings.tex="latex";
import three;
unitsize(1cm);
draw('en 3D : $B$ et B',(0,0,0)--(10,0,0));
```

then asy -kf pdf test.asy works (test.pdf contains line and text) and test_.tex is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newbox\ASYbox
\newdimen\ASYdimen
\def\ASYprefix{}
\long\def\ASYbase#1#2{\leavevmode\setbox\ASYbox=\hbox{#1}%\ASYdimen=\ht\ASYbox%
\setbox\ASYbox=\hbox{#2}\lower\ASYdimen\box\ASYbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
\textheight=2048pt
\textwidth=2048pt
\begin{document}
\makeatletter%
\let\ASYencoding\f@encoding%
\let\ASYfamily\f@family%
\let\ASYseries\f@series%
\let\ASYshape\f@shape%
\makeatother%
\fontsize{12.000000}{14.400000}\selectfont%
\usefont{\ASYencoding}{\ASYfamily}{\ASYseries}{\ASYshape}%
\special{ps:
/ASYx {( ) print ASYX sub 12 string cvs print} bind def
/ASYy {( ) print ASYY sub 12 string cvs print} bind def
/ASY1 true def
/show {ASY1 {/ASYX currentpoint pop def /ASYY currentpoint exch pop def /ASY1 false def} if currentpoint newpath moveto false charpath {(M) print ASYy ASYx} {(L) print ASYy ASYx} {(C) print ASYy ASYx ASYy ASYx ASYy ASYx} {(c) print} pathforall} bind def /V {ASY1 {/ASYX currentpoint pop def /ASYY currentpoint exch pop def ASY1 false def} if Ry neg Rx 4 copy 4 2 roll 2 copy 6 2 roll 2 copy (M) print ASYy ASYx (L) print ASYy add ASYx (L) print add ASYy add ASYx (L) print add ASYy ASYx (c) print} bind def}
en 3D : $B$ et B\ %
\end{document}
```

The same if I replace "latex" with "pdflatex".

If I replace "latex" with "xelatex",

```
settings.tex="xelatex";
```

then asy -kf pdf test.asy does not work (only line, no text) and text_.tex is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newbox\ASYbox
\newdimen\ASYdimen
\def\ASYprefix{}
\long\def\ASYbase#1#2{\leavevmode\setbox\ASYbox=\hbox{#1}%\ASYdimen=\ht\ASYbox%
\setbox\ASYbox=\hbox{#2}\lower\ASYdimen\box\ASYbox}
\pagestyle{empty}
\textheight=2048pt
\textwidth=2048pt
\begin{document}
\makeatletter%
\let\ASYencoding\f@encoding%
\let\ASYfamily\f@family%
\let\ASYseries\f@series%
\let\ASYshape\f@shape%
\makeatother%
\fontsize{12.000000}{14.400000}\selectfont%
\usefont{\ASYencoding}{\ASYfamily}{\ASYseries}{\ASYshape}%
en 3D : $B$ et B\ %
\end{document}
```

I suppose that we have a problem...

PS: Manjaro Linux, Asymptote 2.79, texlive 2022.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem is now clearly identified.